# Azure Notification Hub: Schedule Mobile App API

Tags: c#, android, azure, xamarin.forms, azure-notificationhub

I have a Xamarin.Forms app with Azure Mobile App API (.Net) and am trying to implement the push notification feature.

Basically we're going to generate some transactions using scheduled jobs during the day, and notify respective users if any transaction belongs to them.
How can I create a job to execute the API to trigger the notification in Azure?
I saw the [azure article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dn790626.aspx) , but not sure where to put this code and publish to Azure. Or just create a console application and create a *webjob* in Azure

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@RandeepSingh, there are two ways for scheduling a job which are using WebJobs or using Azure Scheduler.

1. For using WebJobs, you can create & deploy a console app with the Notification API as a WebJob, and set up the trigger for the WebJob.

As reference, there is an [article](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/websites-webjobs-resources/) listed the helpful document resources.

You can follow the figure below to add a WebJob for your Mobile App.
[image]

2. For using Azure Scheduler, you can create a web api in your Mobile App as the scheduled job for calling via an scheduler. You can refer to the [tutorial](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/scheduler-get-started-portal/) to know how to use Azure Scheduler.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend going through [Notification Hubs Overview](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/notification-hubs-push-notification-overview/) first to get a general idea of what the service offers.

In particular, this diagram might be helpful:
[image]

The way it applies to your scenario is:

- Each time a user opens your app you [(re-)register a device with Azure Notification Hubs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dn530747.aspx) and [associate a tag with it](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dn530749.aspx)
- You'll have to find a way to map results of your generated transactions to those tags and then [send notifications to those tags](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/notification-hubs-aspnet-backend-windows-dotnet-wns-notification/)

Also, you might find [Android Xamarin tutorial useful](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/xamarin-notification-hubs-push-notifications-android-gcm/). (Guessing by the tags that you used, but [there's also an iOS one](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/xamarin-notification-hubs-ios-push-notification-apns-get-started/).)

Comment: I understand the concept of notification hub. Just fishing idea for best way to trigger them in a batch job.

Comment: @RandeepSingh does [Azure Notification Hubs -- Notify Users with .NET backend](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/notification-hubs-aspnet-backend-windows-dotnet-wns-notification/) article help?

Comment: am actually looking some sort of following implementation https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/notification-hubs-send-push-notifications-scheduled/ for my scenario.

Comment: Hi, @RandeepSingh, did you find any example of implementation for scheduled notifications?

Comment: Hi @alminh, I yet to implement this, but reference by Peter above is close to my required solution.